# Overview of windows (Expose on OSX) for Windows

Tags: gratis, windows-7, window-manager

I am looking for a program to show an overview of all the open (and minimzed) programs when I press a keyboard shortcut.

This is basically the OSX Expose feature, but for Windows.

Requirements:

- free
- show open and minimized programs
- show live preview of program
- can switch to any window by clicking the thumbnail
- run on Windows 7 64 bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Switcher](http://insentient.net/):

- Windows Vista/7 + Aero
- free
- show open and minimized programs
- show live preview of program
- can switch to any window by clicking the thumbnail
- many customizable shortcuts
- works with several monitors

[image]

[image]

I have also heard of [Mission Control / Expose Clone W7](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcsoft/) but I have never tried this one, they seem to make their best to sell the commercial version of the product and it might not be very multi-monitor friendly.